# Prevent Markdown from turning links into other links

Tags: feature-request, markdown

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/ec8be18d-fa39-4642-a6bb-e6f5e7453e65/view-source) happened recently, and tripped up the mod who reviewed the flags. Can Markdown be prevented from linkifying text which is itself a complete, and different url? I mean, it's just amending a regex, how hard could it be?

Comment: This seems like it should be on meta.se instead of just meta.arqade

Comment: The difficulty is inverse to the estimated difficulty of the layman.

Comment: @GodEmperorDune It doesn't matter, all meta feature requests are processed.

Comment: "How hard could it be" ~ Famous last words

Comment: @fredley See the [kbd style](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4633) question. 3 years *and* I had to chase up one of the devs on Meta.SE